# Groovy DSL given syntax validation

Tags: groovy, syntax, closures

Actually I'm experimenting writing a DSL with groovy. So far ...

There are some things unclear to be regarding delegation and intercepting unwanted (Closure) structures:

first of all: How can I throw a (type of?) Exception to point to the correct line of code in the DSL that fails?

assuming

```
abstract MyScript extends Script {
  def type(@DelegateTo(MyType) Closure cl) {
    cl.delegate = new MyType()
    cl()
    this
  }
}
```

under

```
new GroovyShell(this.class.classLoader, new CompilerConfiguration(scriptBaseClass: MyScript.name)).evaluate(…)
```

the passed DSL / closure

```
type {
  foo: "bar"
}
```

passes silently.

I'm aware of, that `foo:` is just a POJ label but I'm not that sure what that defined Closure is interpreted as?
Neither did I found anything regarding the AST metaprogramming to get in touch of any defined labels to use them?

---

giving in

```
type {
  foo = "bar"
}
```

it's clear that he will try to set the property foo, but do I really have to intercept unwanted fields/props by

```
class MyType {
    def propertyMissing(String name) {
       … // where I'm unable to println name since this leads to field access 'name' ... 
    }
}
```

while user is still allowed to pass

```
type {
  foo "bar"
}
```

which leads to method not defined .. so I have to write additionally some metaClass.methodMissing or metaClass.invokeMethod stuff ..

---

meanwhile I tend to dismiss any closures in my dsl only working with simple

```
def type(Map vars) {
   store << new MyType(vars)
   // where in the constructor I was forced to write metaClass stuff to validate that only fields are given in the map that are defined in the class 
}
```

that works, but both drafts are not what I expected to do when reading "groovy is so great for making DSLs" ...

Comment: Has my answer been helpful? Do you have any further questions?

Answer (score 0):

I would experiment with the different options and then settle for one.

To guide your users you should give feedback similar to that of the regular compiler (i.e. line-number and column, maybe the expression).

Enforcing the correctness of the input can be non-trivial -- depending on your DSL.

For example:

```
type {
  foo: "bar"
}
```

Is just a closure that returns the String `bar`. Is that something your user is supposed to do? The label will be part of the AST, AFAIK in `org.codehaus.groovy.ast.stmt.Statement.statementLabels`. If you want this syntax to assign something to `foo` then you'll need to rewrite the AST. The Expression could become a Declaration for the local Variable `foo` or could become an assignment for the Field foo. That's really up to you, however, Groovy gives you some capabilities that make creating a DSL easier:

You already used `@DelegateTo(MyType)` so you could just add a Field `foo` to `MyType`:

```
class MyType {
    String foo
}
```

And then either use `@CompileStatic` or `@TypeChecked` to verify your script. Note that `@CompileStatic` will deactivate Run-time Metaprogramming (i.e. `propertyMissing` etc. won't be called anymore.) while `@TypeChecked` does not. This, however, will only verify Type-Correctness. That is: assigning to anything but a declared Field will fail and assigning an incompatible Type will fail. It does not verify that something has been assigned to `foo` at all. If this is required you can verify the contents of the delegate after calling the Closure.